# access an element with data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I can't change the id, i can't change the name and i need two different classes to style the elements.

It is possible access an element with data () ? basically, how can i access `data-arrow="el"` ?

```
  $(".vote").data("arrow");
  $(".vote").click(function () {//here i need a selector that should have a permanent name

  //some code
  });

<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $id ?>" name="up" data-arrow="el">up</a>
<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $id ?>" name="down" data-arrow="el">down</a>
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a.vote[data-arrow='el']").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/yzD7q/).

This is jQuery's [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

But wouldn't you be better off selecting all `a` elements with the class `vote`? Like so:

```
$("a.vote").click(function(){...});
```

Also, it's recommended to use `on()` for event handling:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.vote[data-arrow='el']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/yzD7q/1/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access the clicked-on element's data from within the click handler, you would do that like this:

```
$(".vote").click(function () {
    var arrow = $(this).data("arrow");
    // do whatever you want with the value of the arrow variable
});
```

If you're trying to make a selector using the data-arrow value, you can (as in Purmou's post), but it would be much cleaner to just add yet another class and use that in the selector as in:

```
<a href="" class="vote el" id="<?php echo $id ?>" name="up">up</a>
```

and the jQuery selector to select just those elements:

```
$(".vote.el")
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this is the case--both the links have the same value for `data-arrow`. He just wants a way to attach the click to the element by selecting it with the data attribute.

Comment: when i addClass(someclass) i will remove the .vote, so the click handler will stops to work.

Comment: @user947462 - `.addClass("someClass")` adds a new class - it doesn't remove the existing classes.  But you can remove the `.vote` from the selector if you want to and use `$(.el)` as the selector if you don't want `.vote` in the selector.  Classes are much cleaner in selectors and browsers are generally much more optimized to select by class than be data attribute.